# Why is it important to release energy as quickly as possible to perform a vertical jump?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, newtonian-gravity, biophysics

Let's assume that we create this mechanism, where we must decide if the actuating cylinders are double-acting hydraulic or pneumatic with a spring inside.
the goal is for the mechanism to suddenly extend to achieve a jump.

What defines that a vertical jump is high? Is the force that the actuators can make so that the torque generated in that knee generates that the lower part of the bar makes a force against the ground strong enough for the mechanism to jump? Or is it simply the speed at which the actuators actuate and that is the key for the system to clear the ground?

[image]

[image]

Comment: How should the cylinders excite a jump? If fixed to the plate they can only turn it. Please elaborate

Comment: If the right lever is acted on, how would the jumping thing be attached when it is nearly hanging. So you care about horizontal velocity?

Comment: now I will attach a picture

Comment: @planetmaker The reaction force generated by **FTransference** is what will drive the jump